# Looking for a solution to check if the image size matches my requirements in python

Tags: python, compare, python-imaging-library

I have a list of dimensions like (120x600 & 160x600 & 300x250 & 300x600 & 728x90) and im trying to check if images in a folder has the right dimensions or not.

I tried the code below but i couldnt find how to setup a list with dimensions like i mentioned above.

```
import os
from PIL import Image 
folder_images = "c:/photos"
size_images = {} # Use curly braces instead for they're faster
comp_img = [(120,600) ,(160,600) ,(300,250) ,(300,600), (728,90)]
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for path_image in filenames:
        image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
        with Image.open(image) as img:
            img_dim = img.size
            if img_dim in comp_img:
                size_images[path_image] = {'Img width': img_dim[0], 'Img heigth': img_dim[1]}

                if (img_dim[0], img_dim[1]) in comp_img:
                    print(size_images)
                    print("correct")
                else:
                    print("wrong")
```

Comment: will this help `x=[[120,240],[130,260]]` list of tupples where 1st entry is height and 2nd entry is width

Comment: What would the output like? Is it the list of images whose dimensions are any of the item in the list [(120,600) ,(160,600) ,(300,250) ,(300,600), (728,90)] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import os
from PIL import Image 
folder_images = "c:/photos"
size_images = {} # Use curly braces instead for they're faster
comp_img = [(120,600) ,(160,600) ,(300,250) ,(300,600), (728,90)]
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for path_image in filenames:
        image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
        with Image.open(image) as img:
            img_dim = img.size
            if img_dim in comp_img:
                size_images[path_image] = {'Img width': img_dim[0], 'Img heigth': img_dim[1]}
```

Put all possible  'right' dimensions in a list. Check if the dimension tuple is in the pre-defined list, if present then assert the image file path to the dictionary as key and their width and height inside another dict as values.

It should give output like :
`size_images = {'path/to/img': {'Img width': 120, 'Img heigth': 600}}`

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code according to your answer. Also added print functions from @Amir but if print works but else doesnt work. I get no print on screen if img_dim is not in comp_img.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a list of sets of correct dimension:

```
correct_dimension = [(120,600), (160,600), (300,250), (300,600), (728,90)]
```

and then see if the image dimension is in this list:

```
if (width,height) in correct_dimension:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("wrong")
```